# Cassandra Cqlsh is not working

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I've just started working with Cassandra (homebrew install), version 3.7 and cqlsh version 5.0.1. , OS X El Capitan

Cassandra starts up fine and the cluster is operational instantly.

Cqlsh is not working (on any of the nodes) and emits the following error:

> ```
> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1':
> error(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error:
> Connection refused")})
> ```

Comment: Did you double check that the port is correct?

Comment: Check your `nodetool status`.  The IP address you see is the one you should specify with the cqlsh command (it's probably not 127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Edit cqlsh and change DEFAULT_HOST = IP and then run cqlsh.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first step you should be doing is running netstat -ntpl. This should list down all the ports active on the system. Check for **Local Address** there you shall find a IP prepended with 9042.

Use this IP to connect ie **cqlsh IP** . If you do not find the 9042 port in the netstat output than check your cassandra.yaml file. Grep for native_transport_port see if it is 9042 or something different.

If different than connect on that port via cqlsh.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if someone else gets it.

I'm running `[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4]`.

Add `start_native_transport: true` field in `cassandra.yaml` file, by default it doesn't enables it and so no rpc communication with client.

Now try connecting with `cqlsh rpc_endpoint(rpc addr set in cassandra.yaml)`.